# Spring RabbitMQ anonymous queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Am new to Spring-rabbitMQ.I have the following question..Please correct if am wrong:

I have three instances of application namely.

Instance1
Instance2
Instance3

Note: These instances need not be fixed number.All these instances listen to the same exchange..As the number of instances is not fixed, my requirement is the same message shuld be recieved by all three/(number can ) be variable..how to achieve this using spring-amqp

If declare queue name and bind that to exchange messages will be split across the instances..but i want the rabbitmq messages(messages from exchanges) to all the queues..How can we achieve  this ..I heard some thing like anonymous queues...

How to achieve this programatically in spring not through xml declaration and using SPEL to declare the queue id

Step 1: Create connection factory
Step 2: Create exchange
Step 3: Create a queue
Step 4:Create AMQP admin and then declare that queue
Step 5: Bind a queue to exchange

Also on stopping the instance the queue should get autodeleted..should theis be given in post-construct?

The present code is as simliar as follows:

```
CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory("192.168.1.10", 5672);

    RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(cf);

    FanoutExchange testExchange = new FanoutExchange("testExchange", true, false);
    admin.declareExchange(testExchange);

    Queue testQueue = new Queue("testQueue", true, false, true);
    admin.declareQueue(testQueue);

    admin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(testQueue).to(testExchange));

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    container.setRabbitAdmin(admin);

    container.setQueues(testQueue);
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter() {
        public void handleMessage(String text) {
            System.out.println("Received : " + text);
        }
    });
    container.afterPropertiesSet();

    container.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You go right way with `autodeleted` queues, but they might not be `anonymous`, although may be unique per instance.

The main feature here for your is `Fanout Exchange`. Exactly this Exchange is able to send the same message to all subscribed (bound) queues.

You can find more info in the RabbitMQ [Tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html).

Comment: we are already using fanout exchange..but the problem is we are using spring amqp in which we set edscontainer.setQueueNames(queue_name); how to achive this using auto delete queues

Comment: Basically how can we handle this scneario  ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();

AmqpAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
admin.declareQueue(new Queue("myqueue"));

Comment: ??? In general you don't need to do that manually. The `RabbitAdmin` takes care about all `entities` and binding between them automatically. If they are declared as beans, of course. See `Queue` ctors. `autoDelete` is in one of them.

Comment: In our case its declared as bean..So instead of creating a bean what should be exactly done..can u please provide some basic rought sample code..am very much new to rabbitMQ terminology

Comment: You can just read the Spring AMQP Reference Manual: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/. Take a look into Spring AMQP Samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples. Or just study test-cases from the core project. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/JavaConfigFixedReplyQueueTests.java.

Comment: @ArtemBilan...I am facing this problem when tried to implement the anonymous queue..reply-text=RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue

Comment: Looks like you have some misconfiguration and some one keeps lock on your queue or you try to access to it from different consumers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107575/discussion-between-svs-teja-and-artem-bilan).